# How to calculate monthly data from a daily netcdf

Tags: r, netcdf, cdo-climate

I was able to open a netcdf file in R using the package "ncdf4" and extract rainfall (using ncvar_get). However I can't find information on how to calculate monthly values from daily values. Is this possible while staying in the netcdf format or should I convert it to something else? - but what format would keep the lat, long and time information associated with each rainfall value? 
I am not familiar with netcdfs so any help will be appreciated.

Comment: For this kind of data analysis, I strongly suggest you to use the [Climate Data Operators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Climate_Data_Operators) (CDO). It is fast and simple. CDO is not very good if you want to perform high level analysis, but works very well in this case. The operator you are looking for is _monmean_

Answer (score 4):

The exact command with `cdo` is

```
cdo monmean in.nc out.nc
```

I have posted a [video tutorial on temporal statistics](https://youtu.be/pD1r12pklEo) in cdo here.

**EDIT:**

As in the comment of J W you can also calculate the "average" instead of the "mean"

```
cdo monavg in.nc out.nc
```

The difference between the two is in the way they handle missing data. **monmean** ignores missing values, while **monavg** includes missing. Quoting the manual: "the mean of 1, 2, miss and 3 is (1+2+3)/3 = 2, whereas the average is (1+2+miss+3)/4 = miss/4 = miss" - [see section 2.8 of the manual](https://code.mpimet.mpg.de/projects/cdo/wiki/Cdo#Documentation) for more details.

I have posted a [video tutorial on the difference between mean and avg  here](https://youtu.be/E-ehL3N0Cjo).

Last, but not least, you can also use CDO commands directly from R [using this package which provides R wrappers for CDO](https://github.com/markpayneatwork/ClimateOperators)

Comment: Also `cdo monavg in.nc out.nc`

Comment: Yes good addition thanks - but readers should note that these are not the same calculations if there are missing values in the data - monmean ignores missing values, while monavg includes missing.  quoting the manual: "the mean of 1, 2, miss and 3 is (1+2+3)/3 = 2, whereas the average is (1+2+miss+3)/4 = miss/4 = miss" - see section 2.8 for more details.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not an R programmer but I can recommend the command-line tools `nco` and/or `cdo` for these sorts of operations

http://nco.sourceforge.net/nco.html -- see averagers `nces`, `ncra` and `ncwa`.  You probably want the record averager `ncra`

https://code.zmaw.de/projects/cdo -- see https://code.zmaw.de/projects/cdo/embedded/1.6.4/cdo_refcard.pdf for the commands for monthly, daily, seasonal, statistics

Answer (score 0):

Quite late to the party , just wanted to add the following code in **CDO** can easily do the required job as well

```
cdo monsum dailydatafile.nc monfile.nc
```